# trying to create a method to copy the text in a textbox to the clipboard

Tags: c#, asp.net, copy, clipboard

I'm new to C# and I am trying to create a method to copy the text in a textbox to the clipboard. I have searched online and found Clipboard.SetText and Clipboard.GetDataObject as some possible methods but when I start to type them, intellisense does not recognize those. I think I might need to use the system.windows.forms namespace but that also isnt recognized when i put that up top. I should mention this is on a webform for a .aspx site, if that makes a difference. Thanks in advance.

Comment: that will make a difference, since the textbox will be on the client and your code runs on the server. So, you'll need to look into client-side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Great resource here from Microsoft concerning copying to and from the clipboard.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.copy.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

That's not going to work.

The textbox will be on the client machine.

And the clipboard you are trying to access with C# will be on the Server.